# Why do I get different results for this complex line integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, assumptions

I want to compute line integral of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z(z-1)^{n+1}}$ over a closed curve $\gamma: t \mapsto 1 + \frac{1}{2} e^{i t}, t \in [0,2\pi]$ in the complex plane in two different ways but the results are inconsistent. First I used the `$Assumptions=n`$\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ but the result of the integral is different when giving $n$ and explicit value.

The assumptions first
`$Assumptions = n \[Element] PositiveIntegers;`

The first input

```
1/z/(z - 1)^(n + 1) /. {z -> 1 + 1/2 E^(I t)}
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(2  \[Pi]\)]\(% 
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)] I\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(I\ t\)] \[DifferentialD]t\)\) // Simplify
```

The second input with explicit value for $n$

```
(2^(1 + n) (E^(I t))^(-1 - n))/(1 + E^(I t)/2) /. {n -> 6}
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(2  \[Pi]\)]\(% 
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)] I\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(I\ t\)] \[DifferentialD]t\)\) // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: What I see is consistent in version 13.1: `In[24]:= i1 = 1/z/(z - 1)^(n + 1) /. {z -> 1 + 1/2 E^(I t)};
i2 = i1 /. n -> 6;
ii1 = Integrate[i1*I/2*Exp[I*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  Assumptions -> n >= 1 && Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]]
i12 = Integrate[i2*I/2*Exp[I*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
NIntegrate[i2*I/2*Exp[I*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
ii1 /. n -> 6 + .0001*{-1, 1}

Out[26]= -2 I Beta[-(1/2), -n, 0] Sin[n \[Pi]]

Out[27]= 2 I \[Pi]

Out[28]= -4.44089*10^-15 + 6.28319 I

Out[29]= {-0.0019726 + 6.27898 I, 0.00197524 + 6.28739 I}`

Comment: Have you tried other integers $n$? they give $(-1)^{n} 2\pi i$. By the way this problem didn't appear in integrals of other functions. I mean there was no such discrepancy as above

Comment: Is that consistent with *Mathematics* ?

Comment: Re other integers, here are the results for `n=7`: `In[59]:= i2 = i1 /. n -> 7;                                                     

In[60]:= i12 = Integrate[i2*I/2*Exp[I*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]                         

Out[60]= (-2 I) Pi

In[61]:= NIntegrate[i2*I/2*Exp[I*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]                              

                    -14
Out[61]= -1.68754 10    - 6.28319 I

In[62]:= ii1 /. n -> 6 + .0001*{-1, 1}                                          

Out[62]= {-0.0019726 + 6.27898 I, 0.00197524 + 6.28739 I}`

Comment: Re consistency, I would not expect `NIntegrate` and `Integrate to make the same mistakes on a line integral. If there is any disagreement with mathematics, it will be in how I set up the code (that is, user error on my part).

Comment: I now get `-2 I Beta[1/2, -n, 0] Sin[n Pi]` in Mathematica 13.2 which is $0$ when $n < 0$ and `Indeterminate` when $n \ge 0$ . But if I add assumptions it's always zero, *even if I assume n > 0* !